# Redirect query with specific word in the string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am wanting to redirect any search query in the folder **/catalogsearch/result/?q=** that contains .com

This can be redirect to www.example.com/no-route

an example I would like to redirect would be www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=spamwebsite.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make corresponding regex to `QUERY_STRING`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)q=([^&]+)\.com(.*)$
RewriteRule ^catalogsearch/result/test /no-route [R=301]
```

Comment: @Michael You sure you've added `RewriteEngine On` and you have enabled rewrite module?